# Complex numbers - supremum

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

For any complex numbers $z$ and $w$, find $\sup\limits_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}\left|z+e^{i\theta}w\right|$.

I have no idea how to solve it. Thank you for help!

Comment: Draw a picture. Fix $z$ and $w$ and look at $z+e^{i\theta}w$ for various $\theta$...

Comment: Consider the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: try to interpret geometrically, with vectors, what this formula means:

- the sum of two complex numbers: a sum of vectors (Chasles relation);
- the multiplication of a complex number by $e^{i \theta}$: a rotation of the vector;
- taking the modulus: evaluating a distance to the origin

Answer (score 1):

Write in polar coordinates $z=r_z e^{i\arg(z)}$, $w=r_w e^{i \arg(w)}$. Then $z+e^{i\theta}w=r_z e^{i\arg(z)}+r_we^{i(\arg(w)+\theta)}.$ It is clear that
$$
|z+e^{i\theta}w|\leq r_z+r_w.
$$
We are done if we can find a $\theta$ such that the above is equality. How can you choose $\theta$ so that this is the case? As has been pointed out, a picture involving vectors may be helpful.

Comment: The answer : $\theta=arg(z)+\pi-arg(w)$?

Comment: Why the $\pi$? In the picture, what do you want the relationship to be between $z$ and $w$ (after rotation)?

Answer (score 0):

What about fixing $z$ and $w$ and work with the function $ f(\theta) = |z + we^{i\theta}|^2 $ ? One can use $\forall c\in\mathbb{C}, c\overline{c} = |c|^2$ to expand the modulus squared and then calculate the derivative to find the zeros.